# Returning EditTexts in alertdialog to MainActivity

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I have designed an alertdialog of which when the user press the save button, it is hoped that it can return the user's entered editTexts (the players' scores) in the alert dialog back to the activity for further processing.

How could this be made? Would there be any samples? Many thanks!!

I have performed the below but the output now is it cannot recognize what is being input and ask user to input non-blank editText (goes through the else route at bottom):

```
public OnClickListener NewRowButtonListener = new OnClickListener()  
   {  
      @Override  
      public void onClick(View v)   
      {       
           AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);  

           dialog.setTitle("Add Scores"); //set title  
           View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_add, null);  
           dialog.setView(view); 
           dialog.create();             
           final AlertDialog test = dialog.create();            
           SlotAlert_add_EditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Slot_Alert_add_EditText); 
           P1Alert_add_ScoreEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.P1_Alert_add_ScoreEditText); 
           P2Alert_add_ScoreEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.P2_Alert_add_ScoreEditText); 
           P3Alert_add_ScoreEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.P3_Alert_add_ScoreEditText); 
           P4Alert_add_ScoreEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.P4_Alert_add_ScoreEditText);           

           Button alert_add_save = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Alert_add_SaveButton);  //find the Button object within the inflated view                                    
           alert_add_save.setOnClickListener(addButtonListener);        //set the onClickListener    
           test.show();     //show the dialog  
      } 
   };
```

and then

```
public OnClickListener addButtonListener = new OnClickListener() 
   // create a new Button and add it to the ScrollView    
   { 
      private String SlotAppend0EditText; 
      @Override 
      public void onClick(View v)  
      {            
            SlotEditText.setText(""+SlotAlert_add_EditText); //try to set EditText in MainActivity using the one in the alert dialog above 
            P1ScoreEditText.setText(""+P1Alert_add_ScoreEditText);  
            P2ScoreEditText.setText(""+P2Alert_add_ScoreEditText); 
            P3ScoreEditText.setText(""+P3Alert_add_ScoreEditText);  
            P4ScoreEditText.setText(""+P4Alert_add_ScoreEditText); 

         if (SlotEditText.getText().length() <4 && 
             SlotEditText.getText().length() > 0 && 
             P1ScoreEditText.getText().length() > 0 &&  
             P2ScoreEditText.getText().length() > 0 && 
             P3ScoreEditText.getText().length() > 0 &&  
             P4ScoreEditText.getText().length() > 0 )             
         { 
            SaveScoresToFile(SlotAppend0EditText, 
                    P1ScoreEditText.getText().toString(),  
                    P2ScoreEditText.getText().toString(),  
                    P3ScoreEditText.getText().toString(),  
                    P4ScoreEditText.getText().toString()); 
                         } // end if 
         else  (another alert message saying please enter valid input) //NOW THE RESULT IS SHOWING THIS!
```

Comment: What you have tried and what problems you have faced ?

Comment: many thanks for your prmopt reply! i have added the codes as above, basically the user to input 5 editTexts in alertdialog and then when click save, it goes on to the addButtonListener. However, the output now is it cannot recognize what is being input and alert user to input non-blank editText (goes through the else route at bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this

```
 Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LeftMenu);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             CreateAlertDialog ();
        }
    });
```

Alert Dialog

```
 private void CreateAlertDialog () {         

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    alert.setTitle("Title");
    alert.setMessage("Message");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

        }
    });
    alert.show();       
}
```